# Write from Shellscript to file when running the script from crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

What I am trying and tried to do:

I've written a Shellscript which should write some logs into a logfile. Something like:

```
    echo "downloaded header" >> log
```

I also tried with cat instead of echo and I've given full permissions to the log so it should be accessible for anyone. If I start the script from the command line everything works fine and the entries are made as expected.
It didn't matter if I gave the full path to the logfile or not, I tried both.

The Problem:

If I run the script from crontab and yes It has to work with crontab, nothing is written into my log. So the echo "xy" >> log doesn't work, neither does the cat.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the filename (after `>>`) just `log`, or is it the full path?

Comment: You need to supply the __complete path__ the log file.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also allready tried this and it didn't work. Thank you anyway. I just edited it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution:

```
cat cronjob
* * * * * echo "downloaded header" >> /path/to/log
```

Then:

```
chmod +x cronjob
chmod +x script.sh

/etc/init.d/crond start  #redhat based servers like centos
/etc/init.d/cron  start  #debian based servers like ubuntu

crontab cronjob
```

Answer (score 1):

Try redirecting to the log file with full path

```
echo "downloaded header" >> $HOME/Log_dir/log  ## just an example
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also allready tried this and it didn't work. Thank you anyway.